# Store multiple results from HLookup in listbox

Tags: excel, vba, loops, vlookup

I am trying to store the results from a HLookup function in a listbox. However, it shows an error 1004 at the row 'set Myrange = ...'.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


'fill listbox with athletes from relevant country
Dim Myrange As Range
Dim Test(4 To 24) As String
Dim name As String
Dim i As Integer

name = Sheets("RelayRankingData").Cells(2, 5)
Set Myrange = Sheets("AthletesTable").Range("A1:L24")
Myrange.Select
For i = 4 To 24

Test(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.HLookup(name, Myrange, i, False)

Next i

UserForm1.ListBox1.List = Test()
'-------------------------------------

'Show form with listbox and transferbutton
UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

I also added some screenshots from the data [Screenshot1][Screenshot 2]

Comment: what exactly is the need in the end? You need a list of all cell-values, that are not in the "myrange"?

Comment: The value in Blad3.Cells(2,1) will vary. When it contains a new value, I need to select a few values from a collumn of which the first row/cell corresponds with the value of Blad3.Cells(2,1). All the collumns are in "myrange".

Comment: It is always just one record to lookup, but multiple columns? And what shall be done with does values, you need them in a textbox, or some cells, added to a tsble,...

Comment: The HLookup searches in the first row for the collumn with the corresponding value. If found, I need the values of row 4 up to 24 from that collumn in a listbox. From the listbox i select them and it puts the selected values in another collumn. So instead of looking at the record, going to the corresponding collumn and copying the relevant values to another sheet, I want a listbox popping up showing data from a specific collumn of another sheet so I can select the relevant values/records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MsgBox in vba does not support the printing of lists naturally the way you attempt it. You will see that if you do `MsgBox Test(1)` it will give you output. However, I suspect this is only you testing if you have the correct output. For adding this to a listbox, this is irrelevant, it can be done as you attempted:

```
Sheet1.ListBox1.List = Test()
```

As per your comments, this is to be put into a listbox on a userform instead, and the ultimate goal is to store row 4 to 24 in the userform initialise code. This can be done as per below:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim Myrange As Range
Dim Test(4 To 24) As String
Dim name As String
Dim i As Integer

name = Sheets("Name of Blad3").Cells(1, 2)
Set Myrange = Sheets("AthletesTable").Range("A1:L24")
Myrange.Select
For i = 4 To 24

Test(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.HLookup(name, Myrange, i, False)

Next i

UserForm1.ListBox1.List = Test()

End Sub
```

Comment: The MsgBox Test(1) works perfectly indeed. However, I still have some troubles with the listbox. It shows "can not find method or datamember" (I changed "Sheet1" tot "Blad3" and ListBox1 is also Listbox1 in my code. I tried withoud "Sheet1" but than I get the same error as before.

Comment: You only get that error when the listbox doesn't exist on the referenced worksheet. Please check if your listbox exists and is on the correct sheet.

Comment: I can not imagine I did not check that. It worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, happy to help. If your question is answered feel free to select my answer as accepted. If not, please let me know what other issues you have. If you have issues unrelated to the original question, feel free to start a new one.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was a little to enthousiastic. I changed "name" into the name of the sheet within " " and had another error of which I thought I was able to solve. However, after solving this one, I had the same error as before. I tried to copy all the code I showed in this topic to the sub of a buttonclick in stead of the Userform_Initialize because the Listbox already worked there. However, now the same code already shows an error (1004) at the "Set myrange = Range.......". When copying back to the Userform_Initialize it shows the same (1004) error but in the "Test(i) = ......" row.

Comment: Would it be helpfull to send the document?

Comment: @Wytze I have updated my answer to include a more complete code, which should work for your case with a few (minor) adjustments.

Comment: Thank you. I copied your updated code, but unfortunately I still had the 1004 "method of select class failed" error, this time at the "Myrange.Select" row.

Comment: The `Myrange.Select` is not necessary, but a simple test if the previous statement (`set  Myrange`) has worked. If this fails, this means the sheet name might be incorrect. It will most likely resolve if you copy the sheet name from the tab directly.

Comment: I checked the name multiple times but still had the same error. To make sure the error was not triggerd by another mistake, I copied only the relevant data to a new worksheet without changing the sheet names (Blad1 and Blad2, because my excel is in Dutch). I also made the button I finally want to use and pasted the last code into the CommandButton1_Click Sub. Also now I ran into the same error.

Comment: Can you update your question with your full current code?

Comment: I did. Thanks for your time

Comment: First of all, `Myrange.Select` will throw an error if you are currently on any other sheet than "AthletesTable" so removing it might resolve your issue (it is a redundant test anyway). Other than that, the code in your question runs absolutely fine. Just make sure that if you run this code from a module, your `Userform_Initialise` doesn't have this code in it as well, as it will attempt run twice and throw an error.

Comment: I deleted "Myrange.Select" and also deleted the code from the "Userform_Initialise". However, I still get the 1004 error. I only found out with F8 that it throws the error after the row "Test(i) = ..." instead of after the "set Myrange ..." as I thought before.

Comment: in that case what happens if you add `Msgbox Name` just after it is defined? Does it hold the correct value you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, it is showing the correct value. But when I stop the debugging at "Set Myrange" and hoover over "Sheets" or ".Range" it shows "Myrange = Nothing". Shouldn't that one be filled?

Comment: Myrange will only be filled *after* that statement is completed. So if you stop debugging after that line it should be filled. The only other problem it could be is that `HLookup` can't find the value in the first row of the range you are searching. If that's the case, it will throw this error as well.

Comment: That was it. Thank you! I deleted the first row and now "Myrange" gets filled. The last (I guess) error now is that it says "Permission denied" at the last row, where it should fill the listbox. When I put an "i" between the brackets it says "The subscript is out of range". Any suggestions on that maybe?

Comment: Might be remnant entries in your listbox. Try putting `UserForm1.ListBox1.Clear` before the `.list` statement.

Comment: That shows the error "Excel Vba runtime error '-2147467259 (80004005)". I tried to search for some solutions, but didn't find it. I will go on searching, but if you are familliar with it, your suggestion is very welcome ofcourse!

Comment: I Copied all my code to a new worksheet and it worked there, so I guess something was wrong with the original worksheet. Thanks a lot for all your help!